# Java: Parameter list without comma

Tags: java, methods, parameters, optional-parameters

I came across a method with a parameter list where the parameter were not separated by comma and no declaration of the variable type:

```
public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice){
```

Later these parameters were called without any further declaration inside the body in an if-else statement in combination with another method:

```
if ((this.type == 0)&&(anotherChoice.getType() == 1)){
        return -1;
```

This is a brief summary of the entire class:

```
public class Choice
{

private int type; 


public Choice(int type)
{
    //initialize the "type" instance varialble
    this.type = type;
}

  public int getType()
{
    return type;
}

 public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice)
{
   Choice choice1 = new Choice(0);
   Choice choice2 = new Choice(1);
   if ((this.type == 0)&&(anotherChoice.getType() == 1)){
        return -1;
```

The program goes on. I really don't get the link between anotherChoice, getType() and choice2. It is a task in an online course and the program works as intended, but I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe I am blind; but I can only see methods that are using a single parameter; so why do you expect to see commas in there? (you only need commas to separate argument**s** ... so plural, not singular!)

Comment: Choice and anotherChoice aren't two parameters. Choice is the type of anotherChoice.

Comment: Is "public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice){" your example of a method with parameter list with no commas?  You *DO* realize that is only a single parameter, right?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Except bad formatting these code fragments seem syntactically correct. What's your problem?

Comment: Thank you guys, I did not recognize Choice as the type of the parameter anotherChoice. There is no coloring in my environment. I am knew to programming, so thank you for your quick help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're new to programming, so I'll give a quick explanation of what's going on.  If I've missed the point of your question entirely, I'm sorry.

This line:

```
public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice){
```

is part of the `Choice` object.  It takes another `Choice` object and compares it with itself.   ...or at least, that's what I would expect.  The code you provided:

```
public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice)
{
   Choice choice1 = new Choice(0);
   Choice choice2 = new Choice(1);
   if ((this.type == 0)&&(anotherChoice.getType() == 1)){
        return -1;
```

is incomplete and I have no idea what `choice1` and `choice2` are supposed to be doing.  The code I would expect to see would look more like

```
public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice)
{
   if (this.type == anotherChoice.getType())
        return 0;
   return -1;
}
```

or something like that.

Does that help?

Comment: yep, I am new to programming. Totally missed that Choice is the type defined as a class. The coloring helps a lot. In my development environment it is not colored and I did not recognize that anotherChoice is of the Choice type. Thanks!

Comment: Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org) will do code coloring for you, if you like.  If this answer helped you out, I would be grateful if you would accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To clear up your confusion, in this method declaration:

```
public int compareWith(Choice anotherChoice){
```

anotherChoice is the parameter of type Choice.

Answer (score -1):

This was my solution for the course. Probably not the best solution but it worked and i receved my grade. I'm at this moment stuck with LAB 04 TASK 3.

```
int player=this.getType();//get value of choice1
int computer=anotherChoice.getType();// this get the value choise2 out of anotherChoise
int som;// this INT i made to make a sum
int result;
result = 0;//i already gave a value on the INT result
som = player - computer;//this is the sum of de values choice1 and choise2

if(player == computer)  //all ties
  result = 0;     
else if(som == -1) //player ROCK and comp. PAPER or PAPER and SCISSOR
  result = -1;
else if(som == 2) //player SCISSOR and comp. ROCK
  result = -1;
else if(som == 1)//player SCISSOR and comp PAPER or PAPER and ROCK
  result = 1;
else if(som == -2)//player ROCK and comp. SCISSOR
  result = 1;
return result; // this line should be modified/removed upon finishing
```